# Repository Inserting c#

Tags: c#, insert, save, repository

**Controller:**

```
var d = new Repository<Department>(new MyDBEntities());

var newDepartment = new Department();

newDepartment.Name = "Software Department";


d.Insert(newDepartment); //I insert data here
```

**Model:**

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext dataContext)
    {
        DbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);  
    }
}
```

I need to insert data to my database.However if i insert data , it does not work , whenever i check my database, data never appears in my database, also i can not see anything like "SaveChanges();"in DbSet.

**Where i miss exactly ?**

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

After Inserting data. I think you need to update your DBSet. go here to have some info :[DbSet(TEntity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding , you still need to call `SaveChanges()` from `DbContext` underlying your `DbSet` to actually save the data to database.

> **DbSet.Add()** : Adds the given entity to the context underlying the set in the Added state such that it will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges is called. [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)]